# Searching a string from keywords in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I can't figure out why this does not work? I am trying to locate keywords from an array in a string and to println the index number of the array in the console. I have tried the "if" statement both with and without the boolean "true"

```
public class Testing 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    String[] keywords = new String[5];
    keywords[0] = "boat";
    keywords[1] = "car";
    String myString = "the banana car";

          for(int a = 0; a <= keywords.length; ++a)

          {

             if(myString.contains(keywords[a])== true)
                {

                System.out.println(myString.indexOf(keywords[a]));
                }
             else
                {
                System.out.println("Those keywords are not in that string"); 
                }

           }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] keywords = new String[5];////////////here you have array with 5 element
    keywords[0] = "boat";
    keywords[1] = "car";
//////////you just full index 0 and index 1
```

then you for loop on the length of **keywords**

```
for (int a = 0; a <keywords.length; a++) 
//////keywords.length=5 , index 0 and index 1 have a value but the other index is empty
```

**So :**

- you need to full the keywords  array :

  ```
   keywords[0] = "boat";
   keywords[1] = "car";
   keywords[2] = //////////;
   keywords[3] = //////////;
   keywords[4] = ///////;
  ```
- or make the length =2:

  ```
  String[] keywords = new String[2];
  ```

Comment: Thanks - I just tried changing

      String[] keywords = new String[2];

and it still doesn't work  :(

Comment: try to change the for loop to :`for (int a = 0; a <keywords.length; a++)` don't use `a <=keywords.length`

Answer (score 1):

you are missing 3 extra elements as you have declared your String array to contain 5 elements

```
String[] keywords = new String[5];
    keywords[0] = "boat";
    keywords[1] = "car";
```

Answer (score 1):

`a <= keywords.length` should be `a < keywords.length` and you should fill the array if you declared it to be of size *5* to have *5* elements (from 0 to 4).

Arrays are zero based in *Java*, so if you have array of length **n** then the indexes are from **0** to **n-1** (which will sum up to *n*)

Another important thing:

In `if(myString.contains(keywords[a])== true)`, the `== true` is redundant, since `myString.contains(keywords[a])` returns *true* or *false* and here you only want to check this. So it's a better style to remove the `== true`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initalized all the elements of your `keywords`, therefore you are going to get a `NullPointerException`

If you only want to check the first two elements that you initialized, change your for loop to the following:

```
for (int a = 0; a <= 1; ++a)
```

Answer (score 1):

This program:

```
public class Testing {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      String[] keywords = new String[]{ "boat", "car" }; // Only 2 not 5
      String myString = "the banana car";
      for( String keyword : keywords ) {
         int index = myString.indexOf( keyword );
         if( index > -1 ) {
            System.out.println(
               "Keyword '" + keyword + "' is in the string '" +
               myString + "' at position " + index ); 
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println( "Keyword '" + keyword +
               "' is not in the string '" + myString + "'" ); 
         }
      }
   }
}
```

outputs:

```
Keyword 'boat' is not in the string 'the banana car'
Keyword 'car' is in the string 'the banana car' at position 11
```

Comment: +1 for using `indexOf` for the search and saving the redundant `contains`. also for the altered output in the `else` block.

Comment: Novice java guy says a big "Thank You" to all of you  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] keywords = {"boat", "car"};
    String myString = "the banana car";
    for(int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(myString.contains(keywords[i]) ? myString.indexOf(keywords[i]) : "Those keywords are not in that string");

    }
}
```

..should work